# Cassandra copy command timestamp column values

Tags: cassandra, copy

does the copy TO/FROM insert or retrieve timestamp columns only in UTC? I have tried loading csv file with values in timestamp column in EST but I see  timestamp value in UTC when querying. Also exported the EST timestamp values but they are exported in UTC. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you share the command you are using? Also, what is the timezone of the machine? (In Linux, run `date` at the command line.)

Comment: Copy tablename to filepath where header=true and delimiter='|';   the timezone of machine is in EST

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve timestamp column with required time zone **cqlshrc** file needs to be modified.

This file can be found in **~/.cassandra**.
If it is not in **~/.cassandra**. copy **cqlshrc.sample** from cassandra/conf directory to **~/.cassandra** and rename it as **cqlshrc**.

Add the following line to the cqlshrc file

```
[ui]
timezone = EST
```

For this to work you need to have python pytz module.
you can install it using

```
pip install pytz
```

After this login to cqlsh and run your query.